# app.assets.get libgdx on a public static function

Tags: java, static, libgdx

I have this function on my xml class is for puting the imagens on a texture , String ficheiro is the name of the file, SpriteCena  is the sprite

```
public class xml {

private static Texture TexturaCaixaDialogo;
private static Sprite SpriteCena;
private final MyGdxGame app;

public xml(final MyGdxGame app){
    this.app = app;

}
```

.................. other code .........

```
public static carregarcena(String ficheiro){
   TexturaCaixaDialogo = app.assets.get("cenarios/cenas/"+ficheiro,Texture.class);
   SpriteCena = new Sprite(TexturaCaixaDialogo);
}
```

}// end of xml class

what it does is to get a texture from my libgdx  texture manager loader
and it give me an error on **app.assets** . the erro is : **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field app**

> the function carregarcena() must be public and static

any solution?

Comment: private final MyGdxGame app; Your app variable is not static, but you're trying to use it within static function carregarcena

Comment: I know that, I'm try to pass  MyGdxGame app variable from my game class, on game class there is a public final MyGdxGame app; incide of my game class

public class Game{

 public final MyGdxGame app; 
public Game(final MyGdxGame app){
   this.app = app;
 }
 @Override
 public void show() {
xml(app)       }
 }

Comment: Best read up on the use of static then. You're not allowed to do that. Your static function can't use non-static variables, which is what the error is telling you, and which is what your code is currently trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get non-static field app from static method, but that is illegal as non-static variables belong to objects, not classes.

You have two ways to get this working:

1. Make app field static `private static MyGdxGame app;`
2. Make your method non-static `public void carregarcena(String ficheiro)`

You are also missing return type of carregarcena.